# Cnpack/CnWizard Code Completion not working in Delphi 10.4 Sydney

Tags: delphi, code-completion, delphi-10.4-sydney

I want to share this for all those who cannot find why its not working.. Normally when you enter a Dot "." there should be a pop-up window as a code completion window but its like nothing ever happens in my situation and not fixed after restarting the IDE.

Comment: You can invoke the code completition window by pressing CTRL + Space

Comment: Yes, but is that efficient doing that every time? and that list is from Delphi itself and not CnPack

Comment: Well, knowing your tool is never wrong. ;-) I've seen people deleting and writing again the dot just for invoking the code completition window. Besides that, I use that keyboard shortcut all the time, e.g. imagine the case where you closed the window accidentally...

Comment: That's right, although triggering the CnPack's window is different and one of the reasons of installing it is to get rid of the Delphi's default window, but yea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the solution:

- go to Tools -> Options menu.
- go to insight options (search it there)
- go to Code Insight tab, then select "Delphi (Classic code insight)" from the code insight manager ComboBox and uncheck the Code Completion option below it, and hit the save. that's it! Enjoy ;-)